# Show a GWT Container from another class in a popup window

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, popupwindow

Hello I've just started programming and now i'm making a university project where I must  get a `gwtcontainer` from another class and let it see in a popup window, don't know exactly how I can call it

This is a part of my code:

```
import com.is.lap.client.gui.Login;

public class StartRU extends TabPanel {

private static class MyPopup extends PopupPanel {

public MyPopup() {
      super(true);
       // Is here where i have the trouble don't know exactly how to do it
      setWidget( (Widget) new Login().getLayoutData());
      center();
    }
}

public StartRU() {


     Button LoginButton =new Button("Login");
     LoginButton.setWidth("100px");
     LoginButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
          public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // Instantiate the popup and show it.
             new MyPopup().show();
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Login` class extends Widget, you can simply

```
setWidget(new Login());
```